# How show zero label for a zero value column of RadHtmlChart

Tags: asp.net, charts, label, series

I have a RadHtmlChart which has a ColumnSeries. The chart does not show any label for a column which has a zero value.
anybody knows how I can show a zero label for such a column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the same question in the Telerik Forums.  It turns out that this is a bug.  The zero is supposed to show by default.  However, they give me a work-around.

Please see this [link](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/htmlchart/show-label-when-value-is-zero.aspx) for the work-around.